# How draw a matrix with coordinates using tikz - Latex?

Tags: latex, tikz

I would like to draw a matrix of one line et multiples columns with specifics coordinates (3.75, 0.5). Here my figure with tikz :

[image]

Here, the result I'm trying to get, but forget the colors:

[image]

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m1) at (3.75, 0.5) { \node{Cpt: & 0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 0}; \\ };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: You can get latex help on the [Tex stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)